# Не загружает на сервер файл более 52мб

Tags: php, apache

Коллеги, добрый день, пользуюсь Open Server, Apache и PHP, не загружает файлы через html форму более 52мб, как решить этот вопрос? В Open Server в php.ini сделал 10000M, где только не лазил, все равно не хочет, как быть?

HTML код:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Андрей</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="script.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Форма для загрузки файла</br>
        <input type="file" name="filename"></br>
        <button type="submit">Отправить</button></br>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP код:

```
<?php
echo "Имя файла - " . $_FILES["filename"]["name"] . "</br>";
if ($_FILES["filename"]["size"] < 1024)
{
    echo "Размер файла в байтах " . $_FILES["filename"]["size"] . "</br>";
}
elseif ($_FILES["filename"]["size"] > 1024 && $_FILES["filename"]["size"] < 1_048_576)
{
    echo "Размер файла в килобайтах " . ($_FILES["filename"]["size"]) / 1024 . "</br>";
}
elseif ($_FILES["filename"]["size"] > 1_048_576 && $_FILES["filename"]["size"] < 1_073_741_824)
{
    echo "Размер файла в мегабайтах " . (($_FILES["filename"]["size"]) / 1024) / 1024 . "</br>";
}
elseif ($_FILES["filename"]["size"] > 1_073_741_824)
{
    echo "Размер файла в гигабайтах " . ((($_FILES["filename"]["size"]) / 1024) / 1024) / 1024 . "</br>";
}
echo "Тип файла - " . $_FILES["filename"]["type"] . "</br>";
echo "Временный файл в котором сохранен загруженный файл - " . $_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"] . "</br>";
?>
```

Вот что выдает сервер:

> Warning: POST Content-Length of 966712212 bytes exceeds the limit of 52428800 bytes in Unknown on line 0

Comment: ```post_max_size```?

Comment: 10000M, возможно не там указываю?

Comment: возможно, что говорит ```<?php echo phpinfo()?>``` ?

Comment: Как раз таки здесь пишет 50M, но в конфигурации я указал 10000M, как быть?

Comment: Получилось, необходимо было просто перезапустить сервер, спасибо за команду)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правой кнопкой по флажку. "Дополнительно" -> "Конфигурация" -> "PHP" 
Там поля нужно увеличить числа:
post_max_size                = 512M
upload_max_filesize          = 512M

Comment: Warning: POST Content-Length of 966712212 bytes exceeds the limit of 52428800 bytes in Unknown on line 0
Всё так же ://

Comment: Более того, я прописал по 10000M, тщетно

Comment: Я дундук, нужно было просто перезапустить сервер, спасибо)))